# array definition vs array declaration

Tags: c

I have a global array. The memory of this array will be allocated from data segment. 
I get confused what should I call this array. Is it array declaration or array definition?
I think since the memory is allocated this should be array definition.

```
int array[4][5][2]; //  declaration or definition? 4*(4+5+2) bytes will be allocated
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.7 Declarations)

> 5 A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set
>   of identifiers. A **definition** of an identifier is a declaration for
>   that identifier that:
>
> — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;

As you noted yourself the memory for the array is reserved in data section then you have a declaration of an array that at the same time is a definition.

Answer (score 0):

In that case it's both: declaration + definition.

If you have in a separate file something like:

```
extern int array[4][5][2];
```

Then that's only declaring it, since definition occurs in other "external" file.